# Typescript can't import files without extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, webpack

I am trying to import files in my new Angular2 project.
The entry file "main.ts" is able to import an other typescript file using:

```
import { AppModule }              from './module/app.module';
```

"app.module.ts" on the other hand is not able to import a ts file without a file extension:

```
import { AppComponent }             from '../component/app.component';
```

If I add ".ts" to the file name everything works as expected...

What is my mistake? I assume I am doing everything as per angular guide (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html)

I have node 6.9.4, npm 4.2.0, typescript 2.3.2, Angular 4.1.0 and Webpack 2.5.1 installed

My tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    }
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(html|htm|php)$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
                    loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap'
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: '../../template/base/app.php'
        })

        // new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    }
};
```

Comment: Typescript files have .ts extension. Why you don't want to create a file with .ts extension in the first place?

Comment: my files have the .ts extension, the problem is they are not being loaded without putting the extension into the import state

Comment: please, could you share you tsconfig ?

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora tsconfig added

Comment: are you using webpack and ts-loader? if so, please could you share your config too ?

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora yes, i am using webpack and awesome-typescript-loader. But even in Atom it's showing that the file can not be found, so I assume something wrong with my typescript... Did already bunch of research, but am still completely clueless...

Comment: Does VS Code warns you  about it? or is the error displayed when you compile using awesome-typescript-loader ? I am just testing the same and it works for me with ts-loader and VS Code

Comment: My IDE is warning me and I get an error on compiling with webpack (with awesome-typescript-loader and ts-loader). `(7,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../component/app.component'.`. Even if I am trying to put the file in the same directory and try importing it with `import {AppComponent} from 'app.component';` I am getting the same error output

Comment: it seems there is no problem with loading modules that have the extension *.module.ts and if i try to load *.component.ts the error is present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript (at the time of writing in the default classic resolution setting) will automatically detect files that end in `.ts` or `.tsx` and not require an extension in those cases. All other files require an extension as per TypeScript module resolution conventions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Tl;DR: 
If you include `A` without an extension TypeScript will look for `A.ts` or `A.tsx`.

Comment: that's the problem, I was assuming the same, but unfortunately it's not the case. The .ts files are not being loaded, even with the correct extension. In the tsconfig i tried both, classic and node, not working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with classic resolution. It is simply invalid to import a TypeScript file with an explicit `.ts` extension in TypeScript.

Comment: @donnikitos apologies it appears I misunderstood your question. That is indeed weird behavior that I can't explain (why did you mark me as answer haha)

Comment: @KevinPei it's for google searchers. Otherwise it was my mistake.... one of the files had a double *.ts extension (probably happened while duplicating one file)

Answer (score 1):

I realized I have two files with the same name but different extensions. `notes.js` and `notes.ts`. When you have filename collisions, it may require extensions