# Module build failed: Error: Could not find file: '[my-project-directory]\src\App.vue'

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js

[my-project-directory] is the full path of my project.

I started off with the webpack project via "vue init webpack my-project", as per the official Vue.js documentation.

I am attempting to switch to TypeScript by adding vuetype.

I've added a resources.d.ts file to the root of my src directory, though I'm unsure how it's being referenced:

```
declare module "*.vue" {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

I've switched the entry to ts in webpack.base.conf.js:

```
    var path = require('path')
    var utils = require('./utils')
    var config = require('../config')
    var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

    function resolve (dir) {
      return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
    }

    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        app: './src/main.ts'
      },
      output: {
        path: config.build.assetsRoot,
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
          ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
          : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
          '@': resolve('src')
        }
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: vueLoaderConfig
          },
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
          },
          {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
            }
          },
          {
            test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

This is my main.ts file. Note that if I change the import to './App' (without the .vue, it gives me "(2,17): error TS2307: Cannot find module './App'.":

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

In App.vue I've added the lang="ts", used Component from the vuetype libraries:

```
<template>
   <div>TEST</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'

@Component
export default class App extends Vue  {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

The App.vue.d.ts output:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export default class App extends Vue {
    name: 'app';
    components: {
        Hello;
        Game;
    };
}
```

My package.json:

```
  {
    "name": "dominant-species",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A Game",
    "author": "Frank Rizzi",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
      "start": "node build/dev-server.js",
      "build": "node build/build.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "@types/core-js": "^0.9.42",
      "core-js": "^2.5.0",
      "ts-loader": "^2.3.2",
      "vue": "^2.4.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
      "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
      "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
      "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
      "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
      "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
      "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
      "chalk": "^2.0.1",
      "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
      "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
      "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
      "cssnano": "^3.10.0",
      "eventsource-polyfill": "^0.9.6",
      "express": "^4.14.1",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
      "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
      "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
      "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.17.3",
      "opn": "^5.1.0",
      "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
      "ora": "^1.2.0",
      "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
      "semver": "^5.3.0",
      "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
      "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
      "vue-class-component": "^5.0.2",
      "vue-loader": "^12.1.0",
      "vue-property-decorator": "^5.2.1",
      "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
      "vue-template-compiler": "2.4.2",
      "webpack": "^2.6.1",
      "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
      "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.0",
      "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.0",
      "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
    },
    "engines": {
      "node": ">= 4.0.0",
      "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
    },
    "browserslist": [
      "> 1%",
      "last 2 versions",
      "not ie <= 8"
    ]
  }
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      // ... other options omitted
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "lib": [
        "es6", "es2015.promise", "es2015.iterable", "dom","dom.iterable","es2015"
      ],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true, 
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  }
```

And here is the full error:

```
Module build failed: Error: Could not find file: '[MyDirectory]\src\App.vue'.



error  in ./src/App.vue

Module build failed: Error: Could not find file: '[my-project-directory]\
src\App.vue'.
    at getValidSourceFile ([my-user-directory]\npm\node_modules
\typescript\lib\typescript.js:89078:23)
    at Object.getEmitOutput ([my-user-directory]\npm\node_modul
es\typescript\lib\typescript.js:89448:30)
    at getEmit ([my-project-directory]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.
js:114:43)
    at successLoader ([my-project-directory]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\
index.js:34:11)
    at Object.loader ([my-project-directory]\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\
index.js:21:12)

@ ./src/App.vue 8:2-94
@ ./src/main.ts
@ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.ts
```

Versions:

```
node -v
v6.11.2

npm -v
3.10.10

tsc -v
Version 2.4.2
```

Comment: [Vuejs has typescript support built in](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html).

Comment: Yes, but not when using a single .vue file.

Answer (score 3):

did you use ts-loader?

```
 {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    exclude: /node_modules|vue\/src/,
    loader: 'ts-loader',
    options: {
      appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
    }
  }
```

put this in webpack.base.conf.js

Answer (score 1):

[Typescript doesn't work with the file extensions in the import statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43960950/2378943). In addition, [vue has had typescript support](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html) since v2.2.

If you read over the linked vuejs guide for typescript, it should shed some light on your specific set up. It references [a decorator style](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) approach to declaring components you might find useful.

Maybe [play with this cli tool](https://github.com/ducksoupdev/vue-webpack-typescript) to see what webpack + typescript looks like, and it could help inform you how to do your own migration better.

So, maybe try to use Vue + Webpack + Typescript without vuetype - although vuetype could still be useful if you need to generate `.d.ts` files of old-style components, I suppose... I wouldn't know, I stick to the single-file-component style.

Comment: Thanks for the information, it was very helpful. I may use the cli that you mentioned. Though I wanted to keep my vue in one .vue file (for no reason other than preference). And also have the ability to not include all of the package options provided by that particular cli.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue that was causing this specific error. Though I am still working with other issues, it is the answer to my specific issue. It was that the output file from vuetype was "App.vue.d.ts", so the import of './App.vue' was looking at the "App.vue" file directly not "App.vue.d.ts". I can verify this by changing the import to "./App.vue.d" and it picks up the correct one. So it's choosing the exact file name match over the partial file name match, which makes perfect sense.

As a side note, if I want to keep using vuetype to solve my issues, rather than use another cli as Sean suggested, then I would need to figure out how to either wrote out the d files somewhere else or references them some other way.

It's ironic because './App.vue.d.ts' doesn't resolve because of its extension (being 'ts'), but './App.vue' does resolve because of its extension.

Also, it seems as though vuetype doesn't just look for .vue files, it's following the imports somehow, therefore if I set the import to './App.vue.d', it will try to emit a file named "App.vue.d.ts" for file "App.vue.d.ts" and throws an overwrite error (besides the fact that it looks awful!).

Comment: Interesting! Glad you figured it out. Cheers!

Comment: An update on my CLI research.

The CLI option that would make this much easier is defined on this pull request:
https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/pull/797

In the mean time, this example project seems to be a good match for what I was looking for:
https://github.com/johnlindquist/vue-typescript-simple/tree/master/template

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I tried applying the suggestions from the above answers, but I still kept getting the same error. What did the trick for me was changing my `main.js` to `main.ts`, and also changing the entry point in `build/webpack.base.conf.js` to reflect the new ending.